# UpdatePanel Trigger Error. Could not find an event on associated control for the trigger in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble with asp:UpdatePanel and Trigger of ASP.NET WebForms. Trigger could not find the event on my UpdatePanel. I've seen a lot of examples and I copied their implementations but could not get it right. I'm totally new in WebForms. Please help. Thank you.

```
                <tr>
                    <td class="label1">Will use ETL?</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="updatePanel1">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="useEtl" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="120" OnSelectedIndexChanged="useEtl_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                    <td class="label1">ETL Box</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="updatePanel2">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="etlBox" runat="server"/>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="useEtl" EventName="OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
                             </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: With Sujith's solution below (changing EventName to SelectedIndexChanged), I added AutoPostBack="true" to updatePanel1. And, it miraculously worked perfectly!.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your code as follows:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="useEtl" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

the event name you mentioned was wrong that's the reason for not working.

you can also try the following code for the same

```
UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger()
{
    ControlID = useEtl,
    EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged", // this may be optional
}
```

Comment: Hi Sujith, I tried changing it to SelectedIndexChanged however it is not enough. useEtl_SelectedIndexChanged is not being called. But good news is, it does not have an error anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
td>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="updatePanel1">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="useEtl" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" Width="120" OnSelectedIndexChanged="useEtl_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                    <td class="label1">ETL Box</td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="updatePanel2">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="etlBox" runat="server" Enabled="false"/>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                           <Triggers>
                                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="useEtl" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                             </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
```

Comment: I have the same problem with RadioButtonList and updatepanel

Comment: Might be a known bug based on https://forums.asp.net/t/1015714.aspx?RadioButtonList+SelectedIndexChanged+as+UpdatePanel+Trigger